# How to load an Ember.js page inside a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, ember.js

I am working on a scenario where I want to load an Ember component inside a jsp page. Is this feasible? If yes, give me an example.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** Apparently, this is possible ([Ember Islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands) is an example, but is not specific to JSP).  Essentially, doing this sort of thing means loading your entire Ember application in the page, but only rendering your component.

**Original answer:** 
This is not possible.  It's a completely different architecture, and you cannot mix the two.  Among other reasons, JSP is a server-side framework, whereas Ember is a client-side framework.

Comment: Well it is possible if the JSP renders code to start up an Ember app / Ember Islands...but I agree with the latter half of your answer and it is probably what the OP needs to hear.

Comment: I had not heard of Ember Islands.  Interesting.  Personally, I'd still be very wary of this approach.